# HttpClient query occasionally hangs

Tags: c#, async-await, timeout, httpclient

I initialise `HttpClient` like so:

```
public static CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
public static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate, CookieContainer = cookieContainer }) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120) };
```

so all queries should throw `TaskCanceledException` if no response is received within 120 seconds.
But some queries (like 1 of 100 000-1 000 000) hang infinitely.

I wrote following code:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponse> DownloadAsync2(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
{
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse { Success = false, StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, Response = "Timeout????????" };
    Task task;
    if (await Task.WhenAny(
        task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage r = await Global.httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
                response = new HttpResponse { Success = true, StatusCode = (int)r.StatusCode, Response = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) };
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                response = new HttpResponse { Success = false, StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, Response = "Timeout" };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = new HttpResponse { Success = false, StatusCode = -1, Response = ex.Message + ": " + ex.InnerException };
            }
        }),
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        })
    ).ConfigureAwait(false) != task)
    {
        Log("150 seconds passed");
    }
    return response;
}
```

which actually occasionally executes `Log("150 seconds passed");`.

I call it like so:

```
HttpResponse r = await DownloadAsync2(new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://address.com"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Why `TaskCanceledException` sometimes isn't thrown after 120 seconds?

Comment: This is the most complicated code I've seen for cancelling a request after a certain amount of time.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAny` is only workaround to prevent my tasks from getting stuck. It shouldn't be used at all. But first I need to figure out why code in try block sometimes hangs infinitely.

Comment: If it's getting stuck then you have a different problem somewhere else in your code. Are you using `task.Result` in your code somewhere perhaps?

Comment: I don't use `task.Result` anywhere in my code. I added code how I use `DownloadAsync2` method.

Comment: And the code that calls that code? If there is a call to `.Result` anywhere in your code, it can cause it to deadlock and hang forever.

Comment: I don't use `.Result` anywhere in my code. My program keeps regularly querying http rest api where `await DownloadAsync2(HttpRequestMessage )` works most of the time as it should but like 1 of 100 000-1 000 000 queries hang infinitely and `Log("150 seconds passed");` is therefore executed.

Comment: @Misha How often does your app call this Download method per minute (or second)?

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` is an IDisposable, try to use `using()` and see if it helps.

Comment: @AkashKava I use it in my current code. It didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour, probably up to 10 per second, 24 hours per day (on multiple applications). I see a hang about once every few weeks

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour I've seen some issues like that in the past.  My issue happened when load testing a system.  The underline issues was related to the amount of open http connections been left in the system. we played with the number and I think 128 was a good fit for us. like ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 128;

Comment: @JonathasSucupira, yes, I have also raised the ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit as well. I think you are right in that open HTTP connections may be left open. Hence the random nature of this issue. Alas we have no control or visibility of this

Comment: This is a perfect example of how not to write code kids, and another perfect example of how not to set a timeout on a request

Comment: @TheGeneral, we wouldn't need code like this (which replaces a single line) if one in 10 million requests didn't hang ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know with how frequency you call `DownloadAsync2`, but your code smells a lot for **bursting and starving ThreadPool**.

Initial number of threads in ThreadPool by default is limited to number of CPU logical cores (usually 12 for today normal systems) and in case of unavailability of threads in ThreadPool, 500ms takes for each new thread to be generated.

So for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    HttpResponse r = await DownloadAsync2(new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://address.com"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This code with a high chance will be freezed, specially if you have some `lock` or any `cpu intensive` tasks somewhere in your code. Because you invoke new thread per calling `DownloadAsync2` so all threads of ThreadPool consumed and many more of them still needed.

I know maybe you say "*all of my tasks have been awaited and they release for other works*". but they also consumed for starting new `DownloadAsync2` threads and you will reach the point that after finishing `await Global.httpClient.SendAsync` no thread remains for re-assigning and completing the task.

So method have to wait until one thread being available or generated to complete (even after timeout). Rare but feasible.

Comment: I have like 100 tasks each querying `DownloadAsync2` like once a second. This code runs 24/7 and may occasionally hang like once a week. So it is like 1 of 100*60*60*24*7=60 480 000 queries which hang.
I also discovered it is `SendAsync` method that hangs. Therefore I added a cancellation token set to X seconds but even with a cancellation token it sometimes never finishes nor never throws TaskCanceledException.
I assume this is some lower layer issue.
@Misha are you experiencing the same behaviour?

Comment: @LukAss741 So I suggest set your MinimumThreads count in your config to 100 and check its effect (Or even higher to 200 only for test)

Comment: set 100 workerThreads or completionPortThreads or both?

Comment: @LukAss741 Do it like this: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100)`

Comment: @LukAss741, yes, exactly the same for me. Absolutely bizarre. It is SendAsync that hangs

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour, I up my workerThreads to 500, but not my completionPortThreads (stays at 4). Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Misha Based on https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html IOCP uses for marking completion I/O tasks So you should increase that too. 500 is very high and you should set it only for test. try to reduce concurrency in your app instead

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour, I kept on increasing the number to minimise the "hangs". I have many concurrent threads (50-100) hitting multiple APIs at different intervals so having a high number doesn't hurt. I would set it to a lower number if I knew that none of these threads would hang ;-)

Comment: After a few days of testing I confirm that SendAsync got stuck again even after setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(128, 128);

Answer (score 3):

On Windows & .NET, the number of concurrent outgoing HTTP request to the same endpoint is limited to 2 (as per HTTP 1.1 specification). If you create a ton of concurrent requests to the same endpoint they will queue up. That is one possible explanation to what you experience.

Another possible explanation is this: you don't set the [Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netcore-3.1) property of HttpClient explicitly, so it defaults to 100 seconds. If you keep making new requests, while the previous ones didn't finish, system resources will become used up.

I suggest setting the Timeout property to a low value - something proportional to the frequency of the calls you  make (1 sec?) and optionally increasing the number of conncurrent outgoing connections with [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Have updated the DefaultConnectionLimit and it is independent of the timeout. It would seem at this stage that the thread pool possibly runs out of threads, but with a limit of 500 I'm not sure why unused threads aren't put back into the pool. It may be the completionPortThreads limit, but hard to tell as I need to wait weeks (if not months) to see

Comment: Do you need a timeout of 100 seconds? That's definitely a problem in a high concurrency application.

Comment: I have been using DefaultConnectionLimit = 100 for at least a year and it hasn't fixed the occasional hang. I also never query the same url concurrently. I however query several different endpoints of the same host concurrently. I suspect this is some issue with SendAsync method since when it hangs then even cancellation token can't cancel it.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered it was `httpClient.SendAsync` method which occasionally hangs. Therefore I added a cancellation token set to X seconds. But even with a cancelletion token it may sometimes remain stuck and never throw `TaskCanceledException`.

Therefore I proceeded to workaround that keeps the `SendAsync` task forever stuck on background and continue with other work.

Here is my workaround:

```
public static async Task<Response> DownloadAsync3(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, string caller)
{
    Response response;
    try
    {
        using CancellationTokenSource timeoutCTS = new CancellationTokenSource(httpTimeoutSec * 1000);
        using HttpResponseMessage r = await Global.httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, timeoutCTS.Token).WithCancellation(timeoutCTS.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response = new Response { Success = true, StatusCode = (int)r.StatusCode, Message = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) };
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        response = new Response { Success = false, StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, Message = "Timeout" };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = new Response { Success = false, StatusCode = -1, Message = ex.Message + ": " + ex.InnerException };
    }
    httpRequestMessage.Dispose();
    return response;
}

public static Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return task.IsCompleted
        ? task
        : task.ContinueWith(
            completedTask => completedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
            cancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Comment: My software queries apis from like 50 different hostnames and I suspect it is only like 2-3 of them which may occasionally hang forever. I can't say that for sure anyway as it can't be reproduced on demand and happens extremely rarely.

Comment: Why is it a problem if an api never responds? Do you have a list of api calls and then you do a `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: @JohanP if api never responds then `await httpClient.SendAsync` should end with a timeout after some time. The issue is that sometimes it remains stuck forever.

Comment: an api that never responds is only a problem if there is code that is actually waiting for a response for you app to be responsive. What happens today to your code if you get that super rare hang?

Comment: there is always code waiting for api response. If it remains stuck at await then remaining code will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

With [Flurl](https://flurl.dev), you can configure Timeout per client, per request or globally.

```cs
// call once at application startup
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => settings.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

string url = "https://address.com";

// high level scenario
var response = await url.GetAsync();

// low level scenario
await url.SendAsync(
    HttpMethod.Get, // Example
    httpContent, // optional
    cancellationToken,  // optional
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeaderRead);  // optional

// Timeout at request level
await url
    .WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120))
    .GetAsync();
```

[Fluent HTTP documentation](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http)

[Flurl configuration documentation](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration)

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(MAX_THREAD_COUNT, MAX_THREAD_COUNT);
```

where MAX_THREAD_COUNT is some number (I use 200). You MUST set at least the second parameter (completionPortThreads), and most probably the first (workerThreads). I had already set the first, but not the second, and now that it is working I am keeping both set.

Alas, this isn't the answer. See comments below

Comment: ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(128, 128); didn't work for me. Even with that setting I still experienced hang. I will try 200, 200 though. Do you say you currently use 200, 200?

Comment: @LukAss741 - aarrgghh! You are correct - still getting them. Here is another thought: are you accessing the HttpClient in the main GUI thread AND the background threads? I have multiple applications that all use the same lines of code, and it appears the only one hanging is the one where I also do a query from the main thread (all other applications only do queries from background threads)

Comment: @LukAss741 - I think it might be "leaking" worker threads that are not released, possibly with remote request "failures"

Comment: BTW, the application that hangs has one thread that hits an API continuously, and the main thread that hits that API once every 15 seconds (same HttpClient). So very little "contention" and a maximum of two requests at a time. Other applications that hammer the APIs across multiple threads do not seem to be hanging

Comment: I query http only in background tasks. I believe this issue requires deep dive into HttpClient's code which exceeds my programming knowledge.

Comment: @LukAss741 - see my other answer. I'm giving up! This issue has cost me a HUGE amount of time and effort, and seems to only occur under certain circumstances for certain APIs. I just need to make a synchronous call that doesn't hang

Answer (score 0):

OK, I officially give up! I'm replacing the code with:

```
    try
    {
        return Task.Run(() => httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage)).Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        if (e.InnerException != null)
            throw e.InnerException;
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is this code good for. Why don't you use workaround that I provided in my answer?

Comment: @LukAss741 - basically works in one line (excluding the exception handler which is just there to get the original exception). So does what I want - puts a bullet-proof synchronous wrapper around an async method. I see no reason to add extra code for no benefit

Comment: The original issue is all about blocking on background context threads. This code no longer requires any context switching as the block is on the original calling thread - problem solved by removing the problem ;-)